# WebStorm reports error to inline style code

Tags: reactjs, webstorm, inline-styles

I use WebStorm to write TypeScript code. Everything goes well except it always reports errors to inline style code as the following picture. I don't know how to solve this problem after a lot of searching.

```js
import React from "react":

export default function Home() {
  return (
    <>
      <p style=({color: 'red', fontSize: 100}}>Hello!</p>
    </>
  )
}
```

[image]

Comment: try restarting the IDE.

Comment: can't reproduce - the IDE offers the code completion for CSS attributes/values, and no errors are reported; what IDE version is it? Do you have any custom language injections set up in **Settings | Editor | Language Injections**?

Answer (score 1):

don't worry! just the matter of code style .

try to add a space before th last brace , like below example:

[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IuKji.png)

if you want to format code automaticly, change code style in webstorm setting-codestyle-javascript/typescript , like below example:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8m7Rh.jpg)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).